# Casperjs not triggering page.error event on errors in evaluate

Tags: events, listener, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to catch errors on the remote page in Casper.

```
casper.thenEvaluate ->
  document.querySelector("#selector-doesnt-exist").attribute-doesnt-exist = 'value'
```

I have the following listeners set up:

```
casper.on "page.error", (message, trace) ->
  console.log(message)

casper.on "remote.message", (message) ->
  console.log(message)
```

Neither of these is being triggered when the evaluate fails. Is there any way to listen to errors on the remote page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this either, and there's probably a more proper way.

Assuming you only want to catch errors in your own evaluate code (not errors on the part of the site you're loading), one solution would be to wrap the casper evaluate function to include a try-catch, and handle the error by returning it from the evaluate:

```
casper.myevaluate = (fn, args...) ->
  s = @evaluate (fn,args) ->
    try
      fn.apply(this,args)
    catch e
      return {'ourError':e}
  , fn, args

  if s.ourError?
      ErrorHandler.Exception(s.ourError)
  return s
```

E.g. calling:

```
casper.myevaluate ()-> silly
```

...would call your error handler code with `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: silly`